# Merge Library project's proguard rules

Tags: android, proguard, android-library

I have a library aar project which does have progaurd rules in it. My Application has a set of progaurd rules. Is there a way I can merge both Proguard rules while generating a build.

Currently I use the below code for enabling proguard.

```
 minifyEnabled true
 proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

Regards,
Harsha

Comment: Im trying to add that in my Android aar and its not reflecting `proguard.txt` in the aar. Any ideas

Comment: You can see [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system) they added it and did not modify it, hence it *should* work. you should update your post and go into further detail if it is not working and why

Comment: Thanks .. That worked .. In my case I have to use `consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'`